# vscode and edge has different cursor size with system

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I'm on manjaro linux with `visual-studio-code-bin` packcge.

It is strange that my mouse cursor size differs when it move to vscode and other apps.

[image]

[image]

May I ask how I should fix it??

Thanks

Comment: This would probably be better suited to ask on https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

SInce I'm in xfce, so I edited `~/.profile` add a line `export XCURSOR_SIZE=16` to it, fixed